# Subclass: calling a superclass method, correct style

Tags: python, oop, abstract-data-type

Assume that y is subclass of x. Which expression of following calls to a method in x is the correct style? Is there any semantic difference?

```
class y(x):
   def __init__(self,text,s):
      x.__init__(self,text)
      self.something = self.superclassmethod(s) #or
      self.something = y.superclassmethod(self,s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid hard-coding parent classes, which will unnecessarily hamper efforts to use a subclass of `Y` that uses multiple inheritance. For the same reason, use `super` rather than hard-coding `X`.

```
class Y(X):
    def __init__(self, text, s):
        super().__init__(text)
        self.something = self.superclassmethod(s)
```

This will also continue to work correctly should you ever decide to override `superclassmethod` in `Y` itself.